# Abrir arquivo de modo exclusivo c#

Tags: arquivo

Bom dia,

Preciso abrir um arquivo .txt de maneira exclusiva de modo que caso outro programa tente ler receva um aviso impedindo a abertura.

O arquivo que vou ler é um arquivo que contem dados em um layout especifico
e ao abrir preciso ler linha a linha.

Obrigado!

Comment: Ichihara, vi que nenhuma das suas perguntas você marca como resposta. Faça o tour para ver como funciona a comunidade por favor: https://pt.stackoverflow.com/tour

Comment: Rovvan, ok acabei de marcar, vou ver as outras.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Simples, você pode usar o StreamReader. Enquanto não executar o método Close(), o arquivo estará bloqueado pelo sistema operacional.

Código:

```
using (StreamReader rd = new StreamReader("arquivo.txt",Encoding.Default))
{
    string linha = null;
    while ( (linha = rd.ReadLine()) != null)
    {
        //sua linha = linha
    }

    rd.Close();
}
```

Dentro do `while` a variável `linha` representa cada linha do arquivo.